# Ubuntu 16.04 won't accept password if typed slow

Tags: gnome, login, password

This is a weird problem but trust me I've confirmed this too many times.

During login into my Ubuntu 16.04 if I take more than a few secs to complete my password then it always shows me incorrect password. But If I type my password really fast it would accept it and log me in.

I thought this doesn't seems logical but I've tried this more than enough times in last 2 hours. Does any one knows the reason and solution?

Comment: Strange normally its the other way arround ? Are you sure you type your password correctly. Is it your local Ubuntu or login trough ssh ?

Comment: It sounds like a bug!

Comment: @An0n Yes. I'm typing the correct password. It is my local ubuntu.

Comment: try typing in nano and see if there are differences if you type your password slow and type it fast. Seems like a keyboard bug. You could also try to unplug your keyboard and plug it back in.

Comment: Damn! You're right. During fast typing the keyboard doesn't change `[SHIFT] + 2` to `@` symbol. So, when I had typed really fast to set my password it didn't convert `@` symbol to `2`. That's why it only accepted password when I typed it really fast. Actual password was not what I had set. Thankyou!! Do you know how can I solve this?

Comment: I had a dirty keyboard that would type random characters, add a 'g' when I hit backspace, and so forth.  This would show in a text editor, but would be hard to spot (other than as extra dots appearing) in the login dialog.

Comment: Check my answer on your post.

Comment: @SumitDhingra Short version: change your password, and type it slow.  Longer, try with a different keyboard or keyboard driver.

Comment: @ZeissIkon yeah, that would work for now. I'm running linux on Laptop so, I can't change keyboard. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Zeiss Why changed it ? Its even more safe if you don't know your own password but only you know how to input it :P haha. just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

**In Ubuntu go into settings > Universal Access > Typing**

Make sure everything is unchecked there.

### Additional Information :

- **Keyboard navigation** — Use applications and the desktop without a mouse.
- **Manage repeated key presses** — Make the keyboard not repeat letters when you hold down a key, or change the delay and speed of
  repeat keys.
- **Turn on bounce keys** — Ignore quickly-repeated key presses of the same key.
- **Turn on slow keys** — Have a delay between a key being pressed and that letter appearing on the screen.
- **Turn on sticky keys** — Type keyboard shortcuts one key at a time rather than having to hold down all of the keys at once.
- **Use an on-screen keyboard** — Use an on-screen keyboard to enter text by clicking buttons with the mouse or a touchscreen.

**Reference :** [Ubuntu : Universal Acces](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y.html)

Comment: Perhaps you could include some hints why this might work -- what are you unchecking that might make this solve the problem?

Comment: Everything is already unchecked.

Comment: @An0n I found the problem. When I press `SHIFT` and `3` together it still outputs `3` but pressing them one at a time works fine.

Comment: Yeah you need to touch keys with care ;) First shift then 3. ;) Then faster and faster. And before you know you run the keyboard faster then you can speak :P

Comment: @An0n Could you update this reason and last comment in answer so I can accept it?